# Where can I get a Memory Card M-256D or M-256E

Tags: keyboard, synthesizer

These things are really old and no longer generally available, but I'd like to get one of them to get more Patches/Sounds for my keyboard. Is there still a way to acquire them?

Comment: See: [What do you think about shopping recommendations?](http://meta.audio.stackexchange.com/questions/20/what-do-you-think-about-shopping-recommendations)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get M-256E memory cards on ebay